# Handle credit card info on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

How can I validate credit card informations on the client side without passing any info to my server (PCI compliance) ?

The API that I using respond my request with a token, the only info that I need to store on my database. I send the credit card infos for them, and they respond with a token.

I already have the methods to validate the credit card via javascript and make an API call, javascript too, but the info are passing in my server, as I can see on server log:

```
Started POST "/api_checkout" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-04 21:53:02 -0300
Processing by Marketplace::CheckoutController#api_buy as JS
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "number"=>"4111 1111 1111 1111", "verification_value"=>"123", "full_name"=>"Test user", "expiration"=>"14/15", "token"=>"B5E7A1F1-9822-4433-9FEE-30B625B8B070"}
Rendered marketplace/checkout/api_buy.js.erb (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 43ms (Views: 39.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Solr: 0.0ms)


Started POST "/api_checkout" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-04 21:53:03 -0300
Processing by Marketplace::CheckoutController#api_buy as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "number"=>"4111 1111 1111 1111", "verification_value"=>"123", "full_name"=>"Test user", "expiration"=>"14/15", "token"=>"B5E7A1F1-9822-4433-9FEE-30B625B8B070"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 21ms (no problem here, didn`t made the view yet)
```

I dont know if I`m doing the right things, but here what I have today

Here is my form:

```
<%= form_tag api_buy_path,:method => :post, :id => 'payment-form', :remote => true do %>
    <div class="usable-creditcard-form">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="input-group nmb_a">
          <div class="icon ccic-brand"></div>
          <%= text_field_tag :number, params[:number], :class=>"credit_card_number",  :"data-api"=>"number" %>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group nmb_b">
           <div class="icon ccic-cvv"></div>
           <%= text_field_tag :verification_value, params[:verification_value], :class=>"credit_card_cvv",  :"data-api"=>"verification_value" %>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group nmb_c">
          <div class="icon ccic-name"></div>
          <%= text_field_tag :full_name, params[:full_name], :class=>"credit_card_name",  :"data-api"=>"full_name" %>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group nmb_d">
          <div class="icon ccic-exp"></div>
          <%= text_field_tag :expiration, params[:expiration], :class=>"credit_card_expiration",  :"data-api"=>"expiration" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="token-area">
      <%= label_tag :token, "Card token:"%>
      <%= text_field_tag :token, params[:token],:id=>"token", :readonly=> true, :value=>""%>
     </div>
<%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

Here is the javascript that I`m using:

```
SomeAPI.setAccountID("some-id");
SomeAPI.setTestMode(true);
jQuery(function($) {
$('#payment-form').submit(function(evt) {    
    var form = $(this);
    var cardNumber = document.getElementById("number").value;
    //Check with the number is valid
    if(SomeAPI.utils.validateCreditCardNumber(cardNumber)){
       var brand = SomeAPI.utils.getBrandByCreditCardNumber(cardNumber);
       var cvv = document.getElementById("verification_value").value;
       //Check the CVV by brand
       if(SomeAPI.utils.validateCVV(cvv, brand)){
         var expiration = document.getElementById("expiration").value.split("/");
         var expiration_year = expiration[1];
         var expiration_month = expiration[0];
         //Check the Expiration Date
         if(SomeAPI.utils.validateExpiration(expiration_month, expiration_year)){
           var name = document.getElementById("full_name").value.split(" ");     
           var firstName = name[0];
           var lastName = name[name.length - 1];
           //Check everything
           cc = SomeAPI.CreditCard(cardNumber, expiration_month, expiration_year, firstName, lastName, cvv);
           var tokenResponseHandler = function(data) {       
           if (data.errors) {
              //console.log(data.errors);
              alert("Error: " + JSON.stringify(data.errors));
             } 
             else {
               $("#token").val( data.id );
               form.get(0).submit();
            }
             // Send the form
            form.trigger("submit.rails");
          }
          SomeAPI.createPaymentToken(cc, tokenResponseHandler);
          return true;
        }else{
          alert("Invalid")
          return false;
        }
      }else{
        alert("Invalid")
        return false;
      }
    }else{
      alert("Invalid")
      return false
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you need to clear out the sensitive form data before calling form.submit:

```
  $("#token").val( data.id );
  form.get(0).submit();
```

The form needs the sensitive credit card data to perform the validation, however your Rails app does not need this data - it only needs the token.

I typically set the card number to a string containing just the last four digits of the card number like: **** **** **** 1234

Your SomeAPI may already be returning a masked CC back to you, otherwise you'll need to do it via Javascript.

Comment: But what about the first call that I saw on my server ? How I avoid that ?

Comment: @EduardoAlmeida - The first call appears to be coming from the :remote => true on your form tag.  You can probably just remove that from your form if you are planning on doing a non AJAX form submit.  Otherwise, you need to call evt.preventDefault() to prevent the form from submitting within your submit() JS function since you are going to be submitting it yourself.